# Differences in Zero-Inflated Negative Binomial and Hurdle Negative Binomial models in R

Tags: regression, r, logistic, generalized-linear-model, zero-inflation

Lately, I've been trying to model a binary variable through **Zero-Inflated Negative Binomial** and **Hurdle Negative Binomial** models, and I've been having some difficulties interpreting these models (given that they view the zero values in different ways).

This may be a long post, in order to explain myself, feel free to contribute in any way, even if you don't know all of the answers!

Some prior explanation:

- The Y, dependent variable is the number of visits to the ER.
- As for the independent variables, the `N_shots`is a discrete variable,
  referring to the number of vaccines the person has received for the
  treatment of a disease.
- `Sex`is a categoric variable (reference category is being a woman).
- `Treatment1`is a categoric variable regarding any previous medical treatment (reference category is a "no").
- `Age` is a continuous variable, regarding the patients age in years.
- `Duration_Treatment` is a discrete variable, regarding the number of years of treatment for the same disease.

Here is an example of my models:

```
# ZINB model
Call:
countreg::zeroinfl(formula = formula_models, data = ER_data, dist = "negbin")

Pearson residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.5080 -0.4328 -0.3753 -0.1652 13.3770 

Count model coefficients (negbin with log link):
            Estimate Std. Error z value             Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -3.13880    0.26779 -11.721 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
N_shots      0.02851    0.12394   0.230             0.818100    
Sex2         0.91524    0.29869   3.064             0.002183 ** 
Age          0.04989    0.05987   0.833             0.404692    
Treatment1   0.81447    0.21739   3.747             0.000179 ***
Sex2:Age    -0.19152    0.07668  -2.498             0.012498 *  
Log(theta)  -1.25281    0.12618  -9.929 < 0.0000000000000002 ***

Zero-inflation model coefficients (binomial with logit link):
                  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)       -13.1365     7.2919  -1.802   0.0716 .
N_shots            -5.3664     7.5818  -0.708   0.4791  
Age                -3.3659     2.9569  -1.138   0.2550  
Duration_Treatment  1.2241     0.6576   1.861   0.0627 .
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1 

Theta = 0.2857 
Number of iterations in BFGS optimization: 87 
Log-likelihood:  -720 on 11 Df

# HNB model
Call:
countreg::hurdle(formula = formula_models, data = ER_data, dist = "negbin")

Pearson residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.6755 -0.4168 -0.3610 -0.2747 11.1240 

Count model coefficients (truncated negbin with log link):
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept) -10.45782   52.16182  -0.200  0.84110   
N_shots      -0.29871    0.20871  -1.431  0.15236   
Sex2          1.14716    0.52581   2.182  0.02913 * 
Age           0.08981    0.11272   0.797  0.42561   
Treatment1    0.91189    0.35092   2.599  0.00936 **
Sex2:Age     -0.32773    0.14161  -2.314  0.02065 * 
Log(theta)   -9.09058   52.16870  -0.174  0.86167   
Zero hurdle model coefficients (binomial with logit link):
                  Estimate Std. Error z value        Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)       -2.23533    0.34022  -6.570 0.0000000000502 ***
N_shots            0.31902    0.12244   2.606         0.00917 ** 
Age               -0.02794    0.04084  -0.684         0.49391    
Duration_Treatment  0.12178    0.02949   4.130 0.0000363347323 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1 

Theta: count = 0.0001
Number of iterations in BFGS optimization: 36 
Log-likelihood: -718.2 on 11 Df

# exp(confint(zinb_model))
                                     2.5 %         97.5 %
count_(Intercept)       0.02563859711463139     0.07324547
count_N_shots           0.80700910138734661     1.31184157
count_Sex2              1.39071731196458725     4.48465009
count_Age               0.93476469202688406     1.18204305
count_Treatment1        1.47461032943775372     3.45748784
count_Sex2:Age          0.71048216085988625     0.95960032
zero_(Intercept)        0.00000000000122461     3.17549102
zero_N_shots            0.00000000164328036 13275.91540714
zero_Age                0.00010502209542954    11.35303859
zero_Duration_Treatment 0.93729329963267705    12.34070670

# exp(confint(hnb_model))
                               2.5 %      97.5 %
count_(Intercept)      -112.69311894 91.77747350
count_N_shots            -0.70777126  0.11034403
count_Sex2                0.11659446  2.17771976
count_Age                -0.13112102  0.31073630
count_Treatment1          0.22409012  1.59968949
count_Sex2:Age           -0.60528396 -0.05017161
zero_(Intercept)         -2.90214402 -1.56850678
zero_N_shots              0.07904560  0.55898752
zero_Age                 -0.10799434  0.05211119
zero_Duration_Treatment   0.06398202  0.17957812
```

1. First question, how can I interpret each model?
2. In the binary component (zero-inflation component), how should my interpretation be? Should I be referring to the odds of a zero count, or to the odds of a count higher than zero?
3. I've been told to also present some confidence intervals? Why is that? Why are they important to my analysis, and how do I interpret them (from my basic understanding it's to verify the precision of the estimate. If the CI is too wide, then there is a low precision regarding the variable. Please, correct me if I'm wrong)?
4. You can see that there are some (very) odd values in the ZINB confidence intervals (`zero_N_shots`). Why is this happening? (If you sugest removing the variable, I "can't", it's really important to show how the number of shots influences the number of trips to the ER.

I realise that it is a long post, but any answer is welcomed, I'm having a lot of difficulties in this subject.